# How to use dynamic button click event handler without using page init or page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to use a click event handler for my 4 buttons that I have generated dynamically without putting any code in page init or oninit. I have one button that once clicked it generates 4 more buttons. The click event handler for these 4 buttons is not working. Here is the code. Has anybody figured out a way to use the click events in asp.net c# without first putting it in `page_load`? If I can solve this problem, I can solve my real problem in a bigger scenario.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = i.ToString();
        b.Text = "ClickMe";
        b.Visible = true;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(b_click);

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}

void b_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "ok";
}
```

Comment: The reason the event handler isnt working is because the control tree isnt recreated correctly on postback. There is a special page event you should override to recreate the buttons before the viewstate is loaded to get the event to fire.

Comment: Is the number of buttons static? If you know there will only be four buttons, why not just hide the buttons from view until you need them? This way your event wire-up should work as expected with no extra intervention.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Yes, that's the init method.  Clearly the OP knows exactly what he needs to do, and yet he's specifically said he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: Dynamic controls in webforms are notoriously difficult to get to work correct due to the viewstate and control tree - therefore avoid it as much as possible until you know exactly what you're doing (and even consider then whether it's possible to avoid dynamically add controls). If you want to dynamically add controls, then as said in the other comments - you need to recreate them before you can catch and handle the event. Otherwise you'll have to do your own postback and that means more code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ID of your dynamic controls include a distinct keyword. In my example below I prepended "DYNAMIC_" to their ID. Then override `OnPreRender()` like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack && !IsPostBackEventControlRegistered)
    {
        var controlName = this.Request.Form.AllKeys.SingleOrDefault(key => key.Contains("DYNAMIC_"));
        processEventForDynamicControl(controlName);
    }

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

private void processEventForDynamicControl(string controlName)
{
    //Do your dynamic button click processing here
}
```

Of course, if your dynamic controls use `doPost()` (which sadly Button doesn't) you can retrieve the control directly from `__EVENTTARGET` like this:

```
var controlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to load controls inside **Page_Load**. Otherwise, they are not in control tree, and they won't be able to trigger **b_click** event.

```
public int Counter
{
    get { return (int?) ViewState["Counter"] ?? 0; }
    set { ViewState["Counter"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var counter = Counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = i.ToString();
        b.Text = "ClickMe";
        b.Visible = true;
        b.Click += b_click;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = i.ToString();
        b.Text = "ClickMe";
        b.Visible = true;
        b.Click += b_click;

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}
void b_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "ok";
}
```

***Note:*** If you plan to load inside Page_Init, you want to use Session instead of ViewState.

Comment: I'd go with this approach. If not familiar with sessions you could use a hidden field

Comment: ***Hidden field*** is basically same as ***ViewState*** in this scenario. If you use hidden field, you have to use ***Page_Load*** because its value is not available inside ***Page_Init*** event.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I got it working.There is no way around it. You have to use Oninit or Page_load and put your b.Click += new EventHandler(b_click) code there in addition to the PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b); there as well,for the event handler to register properly with the button. The problem with this method is that it places the button on top of the PlaceHolder portion of the web page which is not what I want. I want to beable to place the button at a particular position in the web page. So how do you go around doing this? Basically after the PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b) simply make the button invisible. Then in the when you are ready to place the button in a particular part of your html call PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b) again and make it visible. That works  for me. If anyone needs help with this I can post some sample code and you can test it for yourself. Thanks all.

Comment: Is this not what I said in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38360247/296861)? positioning is totally out of the scope of your OP.